# registering ip addresses but exclude bots

Tags: bots, web-crawler

I'm storing the IP addresses with each request to see how many visitor views I received.

```
Dim clientIPAddress As String = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
locationsDAL.AddLocationView(locationId, "", User.Identity.Name, clientIPAddress, "website")
```

But I notice that this also stores the MSN/Google bots etc that crawl my site.

How can I only store the IP-addresses of non-bots, so of real visitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so what I did is this:

```
Dim clientIPAddress As String = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
If Not CheckIfCrawler(Dns.GetHostEntry(clientIPAddress).HostName) Then
 'log view
end 

Public Shared Function CheckIfCrawler(ByVal hostname As String) As Boolean
    If hostname.Contains("googlebot") Then
        Return True
    ElseIf hostname.Contains("msnbot") Then
        Return True
    ElseIf hostname.Contains("baiduspider") Then
        Return True
    ElseIf hostname.Contains("nipple3.mail.ru") Then
        Return True
    ElseIf hostname.Contains("reverse.wowrack.com") Then
        Return True
    ElseIf hostname.Contains("crawl") Then
        Return True
    ElseIf hostname.Contains("spider") Then
        Return True
    ElseIf hostname.Contains("nipple2.mail.ru") Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
 End Function
```

This way I can exclude most bots by their hostname.
Once every 6 months I will check the DB again to see if any particular hostname has had a lot of views. I then check manually using a IP GeoDB if that hostname/IPAddress belongs to a bot and if so manually add it to the CheckIfCrawler function.

Answer (score 0):

The official modes are

http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/webmaster/archive/2012/08/31/how-to-verify-that-bingbot-is-bingbot.aspx

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.es/2006/09/how-to-verify-googlebot.html

Also, you can detect bots by User Agent or range ips.

Common User Agents:

```
Googlebot
  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
Googlebot-Mobile
  Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8B117 Safari/6531.22.7 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)         
bingbot
    Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
MSNBot  
    msnbot-media/1.1 (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm)        
MSRBOT  
    MSRBOT
```

Comment: Thanks. But that's just a small number (though the most important) of bots. Is there another way I can detect if it's a bot or user-agent where I don't have to check for specific user-agents? Thanks!

Comment: Any suggestions here? It seems too much work to exclude all bots like yandex, yahoo etc. Is there not some sort of header that would be missing if a bot crawled my site so that I know it's a bot?